# SQL with group by and number of rows

Tags: sql

I have one table:

```
ID | domain       | address
=======================================
 1 | example.com  | example.com/siteA
 2 | example.com  | example.com/siteB
 3 | example.com  | sub.example.com
 4 | example.com  | sub.example.com/dir
 5 | foobar.com   | foobar.com/site123
 6 | foobar.com   | foobar.com/site
 ...
```

now I like to know how many "addresses" one domain has like

```
ID | domain       | count
==========================
 1 | example.com  | 4
 5 | foobar.com   | 4
```

my statement is currently

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY domain
```

I know this is nothing but is one table enough or should I split it into two?

Comment: You should really specify your fields - better practice that way.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: e.g. `SELECT id, domain, address ...`.  [Read this](http://satheeq.wordpress.com/2012/10/03/why-select-is-a-bad-practice-in-t-sql/).  (PS: Notice that everyone's answering by specifying the field names in the `SELECT` clause).

Comment: My original query is much complicate so I just go with that basic version. I specify the fields in the end of course, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT domain, COUNT(domain) as Count FROM table GROUP BY domain
```

**UPDATE : To get the Id**

```
SELECT MIN(ID) ID, domain, COUNT(domain) as Count FROM table GROUP BY domain
```

OR, another way:

```
SELECT 
 (SELECT MIN (ID) FROM table WHERE DOMAIN = A.DOMAN) AS ID
domain, 
COUNT(domain) as Count 
FROM table A GROUP BY domain
```

Comment: TBH I think the ID is a bit superfluous.

Comment: i dont know, just to show an idea, question not very clear though

Comment: If you mean MIN or MAX (ID), yes, thats true. but just for the sake of illustration

Answer (score 1):

**[Read Group by](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-group-by.htm)**

```
select min(ID) as ID,domain,count(1) as Count
from table 
group by domain
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for this output:

```
ID | domain       | count
==========================
 1 | example.com  | 4
 5 | foobar.com   | 4
```

This is the query (assuming every address is unique per domain):

```
SELECT MAX(ID), domain, COUNT(*) as count FROM table GROUP BY domain
```

Comment: That wont work, any column is not in aggregation function must be in group by section